# How to measure distance between two coordinates with less calc possible?

Tags: delphi, math, gps, coordinates

I'm trying to make measures using the less CPU possible, so I'm using a constant multiplicator to get to a value in meters like this:

lat1,long1 = Coordinate 1

lat2,long2 = Coordinate 2

```
DistV := abs(lat1-lat2);                  // Get a positive vertical value
DistH := abs(lon1-long2);                 // Get a positive horizontal value
DistGPS := sqrt(sqr(DistV) + sqr(DistH)); // Get a diagonal value
DistMeters := DistGPS*(111120*0.946);     // 111120*0.946 = Constant multiplicator to meters
```

However, the values calculated are going to be added to the previous measures, making it necessary to be accurate. Does anyone know a better way for doing it?

Comment: Hardly (I don't even know where your constant used in your code comes from) :) But for high accuracy use [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula), otherwise deal only with less accuracy. For serious work with this kind of data we were using proven libraries like GEOS and Proj4 for projections (they're both used in PostGIS).

Comment: @Victoria The constant is a very rough approximation of the length of an arc, given an angle, about a sphere with a similar radius to the average of that of Earth.  The calculation is wildly approximate - definitely not to be used for anything serious.

Comment: @J..., really rough. I'm about to release our map solution as open source this year, so I know a bit about this kind of stuff. Still, you cannot beat this code in performance with better accuracy. If you can, let me know (though we're working with more accuracy as default, not Haversine) :)

Comment: I made some more calcs and decided to make a small change:

From 111120*0.946 to (111120*0.946)*0.976 = 102,597

Now using this constant multiplicator the values seem very accurate based on comparations made with the Google Maps distance measure, for 374 meters and 1.51 kilometers.

Comment: If you stick with the basic Pythagoras, as used in the question, then you need to consider that the distance scale for latitude and longitude are different once you move away from the equator.  If you use a different scale factor for lat and lon then you can get a reasonable local approximation but this is quite local.  If moving broader then you need to use haversine or the full WGS84 geoid formula (which you definitely shouldn't implement yourself).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To measure a distance more accurately, you can use Haversine formula, as written in comments. [Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you can see formula and JavaScript implementation:

```
var R = 6371e3; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

If you think that rough approximation is quite good for you purposes, you can make it more precise accounting for distance contraction along meridian (instead of common constant for both coordinates):

```
DistV := abs(lat1-lat2);                  // Get a positive vertical value
DistH := abs(lon1-long2);                 // Get a positive horizontal    value
DistH := DistH * Cos((lat1+lat2) / 2);     // Use average latitude            
DistGPS := sqrt(sqr(DistV) + sqr(DistH)); // Get a diagonal value
DistMeters := DistGPS*111120;  //to meters
```

Comment: Here is an implementation in Delphi: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula#Delphi